# Ubuntu 18.10 in emergency mode after installing Nvidia drivers

Tags: linux, ubuntu, drivers, graphics-card

I just installed Ubuntu 18.10 yesterday. I recently installed the recommended proprietary Nvidia drivers for my system (which has a GTX 1080), `nvidia-driver-390`. When I rebooted my system it got stuck on the loading screen (Plymouth) for a while and then told me I was in emergency mode.

I've tried uninstalling the drivers, reinstalling the drivers, booting into recovery mode (still goes to emergency mode), booting into an old kernel, and I'm pretty much stuck at this point.

I also ran `systemctl -xb | grep error` to find any errors, but the output looks normal as far as I can tell.

[image]

Would anyone mind giving me some things to try that might let me boot normally?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is fixed! Sadly, it was just because of my being an idiot. I had some mount points in `/etc/fstab` that had been deleted and the disks had been reformatted. Removing them from the file solved all my problems.

Sorry if you're having this same problem, although I'd recommend trying all the same things I did, including:

- `ubuntu-drivers list` and then `apt-get remove nvidia-driver-foo`
- Try booting into recovery mode
- Try booting into an older kernel
- `systemctl -xb | grep error`
- `cat /var/log/boot.log`